# finding locus of z using information about $z^2$

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics, locus

I came across this interesting question,it is as follows:

a complex number $z$ satisfies the equation $|z^2-9| + |z^2| = 41$ and we are required to find the locus of $z$ and maximum value of |z|

my approach:

one of the easiest but very lengthy method is $z= x +iy$ putting this into the equation, squaring both sides and equating real and imaginary parts = 0, I finally obtained $|z+3| + |z-3| = 10$ and it is easy to see that $\max (|z|) = 5$.

however we wanted to know if there is an easier and more convenient method to solve this question .kindly help us out.

Comment: Have you tried using the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Toby Mak well how can i use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the complex number Z satisfies $ |Z^2 - 9| + |Z^2| = 41 $ then the true statements among the following are?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760416/if-the-complex-number-z-satisfies-z2-9-z2-41-then-the-true-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle inequality for complex numbers states that $|z_1+z_2| ≤ |z_1| + |z_2|$. In your case $41 = |z^2-9| + |z^2| ≤ |z^2-9+z^2|$.

Comment: how can we find locus using this?

Comment: The same operations for real numbers apply to complex numbers as well. So $|2z^2 - 9| ≥ 41$ which gives $|2z^2| ≥ 50$ and so on...